# Check for certain arguments and assign values to an arbitrary variable

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a program and need to look for one of two arguments set on the command line, and save a value to a single variable based on which one is set.

If I call the program like this:

```
myprogram -a --foo 123
```

I want the variable `action` set to `'a value'`. Call it like this:

```
myprogram -b --foo 123
```

And `action` should be set to `'another value'`. Call it with neither:

```
myprogram -c --foo 123
```

And it should exit with usage info.

Obviously I can do this with some `if` statements after the fact:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-a', action='count')
parser.add_argument('-b', action='count')
parser.add_argument('--foo')
....
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.a == 0 and args.b == 0:
    parser.print_usage()
    sys.exit(1)
if args.a > 0:
    action = 'a value'
elif args.b > 0:
    action = 'another value'
```

But I'm wondering if argparse can do it for me with less code. From what I've seen in the documentation it's not possible, but Python is very very new to me. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is, you will have to have an if: else: statement somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used hapulj's answer, but still ended up with an `if` statement to check if neither was set. Then I found the `ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()` function, and ended up with this, which works perfectly.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
actiongroup = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
actiongroup.add_argument('-a', action='store_const', dest='action', const='a value')
actiongroup.add_argument('-b', action='store_const', dest='action', const='another value')
parser.add_argument('--foo')
....
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now, arguments `-a` and `-b` can't be omitted, and both can't be specified at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `action='store_const'`.

```
In [240]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [241]: parser.add_argument('-a', dest='action',
   action='store_const', const='a value')
In [242]: parser.add_argument('-b', dest='action',
   action='store_const', const='another value')
In [243]: parser.add_argument('--foo')

In [244]: parser.parse_args('-a --foo 123'.split())
Out[244]: Namespace(action='a value', foo='123')

In [245]: parser.parse_args('-b --foo 123'.split())
Out[245]: Namespace(action='another value', foo='123')

In [246]: parser.parse_args('-c --foo 123'.split())
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-a] [-b] [--foo FOO] 
ipython3: error: unrecognized arguments: -c
SystemExit: 2
```

So `args.action` will have `a value' or`b value' depending on the argument.  Note both `-a` and `-b` store to the same `dest`.

I left `-c` undefined, so it uses the normal `undefined` exit with usage.  that could be refined.

Defining a `c` like this would let you do your own exit:

```
In [247]: parser.add_argument('-c', dest='action', action='store_const', const='exit')

In [248]: args=parser.parse_args('-c --foo 123'.split())
In [249]: if args.action=='exit':parser.print_usage()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-a] [-b] [--foo FOO] [-c]
```

If you used `action='store_true'` instead of 'count' for your `-a` and `-b`, you could simplify the `if` tree to:

```
if args.a:
    action = 'a value'
elif args.b:
    action = 'another value'
else:
    parser.print_usage()
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen `store_const`, but had missed the `dest` parameter. Will give it a shot.